# NodeJS Cluster, useful use cases?

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I am researching use cases to introduce cluster computing with nodejs to a few friends.

My goal is to explain a few real life nodejs cluster cases, and why nodejs is helpful at creating those particular cases.

So far, really one case appeals to me:

- **clustering a webserver (like an API server by REST)** (reason: load balancing)

I saw examples about doing expensive calculations, mentioning the advantages on doing so on a different thread/processor.

That lead me to thinking about about having worker pools, each pool doing different parts like handling solely the connection to a database, generating PDFs and similar.

Trying to understand the ties from the worker to the master, I [fiddled around](https://www.npmjs.com/package/runworker) and I am still not sure:

- are nodejs clusters are only suited for having the same process be able to run in parallel (documentation suggests it)
- or does it makes sense to have nodejs cluster workers like separate tasks in pools.

.. resulting in: what use cases are actually real world use cases with nodejs?

Hopefully it is understandable.
Opinions are very welcomed.

Comment: Also, you might find my answer here helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19324665/362536  I wrote it years ago, but I think it's still mostly up-to-date.

Comment: @Brad "Node.js is a bit different. It is single-threaded from a JavaScript perspective, but other tasks like disk and network IO are handled on separate threads automatically." This is interesting, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are nodejs clusters are only suited for having the same process be able to run in parallel (documentation suggests it)

Sort of.  The built-in cluster module is just spawning child processes that happen to be the same script that's running.  You could always just execute child processes other ways.

> or does it makes sense to have nodejs cluster workers like separate tasks in pools

Whatever works for you and your application!  There's no reason to follow convention if you have a reason not to.

> resulting in: what [cluster] use cases are actually real world with nodejs?

*(I assume you were asking about real world use cases for clusters.)*

For most applications (the ones I've seen and use anyway), it's possible to fully saturate/utilize a system's resources with a single Node.js processes.  Just because your code is single threaded doesn't mean all the native code you're calling out to is.  A lot of folks use the cluster module because they believe it's the only way to fully utilize all the CPUs on the host.  This is from a common misunderstanding of the Node.js documentation.

I'm sure there are some applications that are just CPU-bound in that single thread for running JavaScript, but for many, I/O is a much bigger blocker.

Comment: Hi, thanks. That use of the cluster module (using all CPUs) is also what I thought would be the only way - misunderstanding: what else is there?